# How to get a screen shot of a window from command line using window id

Tags: command-line, qml, screenshot, pyqt5

How to get a screenshot of only one window from the command line if I have window id?
[image]

I want to show a preview screen like this for a specific window with qml and pyqt5. What can I do then?

Comment: Several options, using one of the applications that has this as a cli option, using imagemagick's import or using Gdk in one of the languages. What is the context?

Comment: @Jacob Vlijm now I added more details. What can I do with this case?

Comment: Ah, writing a preview application? I hope I can find the time to write an answer in the next few days. In the meantime, have a look here: https://github.com/UbuntuBudgie/budgie-extras/blob/master/budgie-wpreviews/src/previews_creator.vala, line 202-204 are the relevant lines. it's Vala, but the python way is similar. You can do the scaling in one step, and this is the least consuming way. Hope it is understandable. As said, If I can find time in the next few days, I'll write an answer.

Comment: select the window using xdotool . $id I got from name .delay is optional though advisable or put a wait command in after it. .

ids=$(xdotool search --desktop 0 --class  "$name")
and if more than one id you need to make a decision 


xdotool windowactivate --sync $id key  --delay 100 

then use screenshot of that active window

gnome-screenshot -w

make a script and a keyboard shortcut.

Answer (score 2):

You can raise the relevant window with the `wmctrl` command and take its screenshot  using the `gnome-screenshot` command. For example, assuming that the window id is `0x02600010`, you can use:

```
wmctrl -i -a 0x02600010 && gnome-screenshot -w
```

Comment: sorry. I didn't describe what I want. Now I edited my post. Can you give me a suitable answer?